# Save android map as a picture

Tags: android, image, dictionary

I would like to save the camera view of a map fragment with the marker of my location in my android app as a picture, so that I can display it in another activity. Is there any way to do that?

If that doesn't work I thought about just saving the address or location object and to put it in a map view and somehow disable interaction of the user, because it should really just display the location.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a built-in method for that. But first you need to obtain the `GoogleMap` map instance.

```
 GoogleMap map = .....

 map.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                     // Do whatever here
                   }
               });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow. I somehow couldn't find that built-in-method before.